# Two way binding to scope variable works only when wrapping in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I need to make a basic search for some items. I made a simple control, with a button that clears out the search query:

```
<div class="item item-input item-button-right">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Search"
           ng-model="search">

    <button class="button button-icon" ng-if="search" ng-click="search = null">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-close-empty"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

However the button does not work. `search` variable is updated properly, but change is not reflected in the view.

After some digging, I wrapped the query string into an object, making a variable `search.query`:

```
<div class="item item-input item-button-right">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Search"
           ng-model="search.query">

    <button class="button button-icon" ng-if="search.query" ng-click="search.query = null">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-close-empty"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Suprisingly, this works as expected: query is cleared out when button is clicked.

How is this possible? Does `angular` threats wrapped up scope variables differently from those, which are directly in scope?

Comment: That's because of prototypical inheritance in javascript, check this answer (not mine, just great) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Comment: This is the thing I was searching for :) Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
ng-click="$parent.search = null"
```

[`ng-if` creates child scope](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/B2uB8-9_Xbk/-lqd8dVrifoJ), so `search` is bound to scope of `ng-if`

Answer (score 0):

it's all about scope inheritance, which is based on javascript prototype inheritance.

search - in this case it is just a value, that will be overwritten in scope that is created by ng-if

search.query - in this case it's a link to search object property and it will be changed also for parent scope.